# Bash regex to match quoted string

Tags: regex, bash

I’m trying to come up with a regular expression I can use to match strings surrounded by either single or double quotation marks. The regex should match all of the following strings:

```
"ABC&VAR#"
'XYZ'
"ABC.123"
'XYZ&VAR#123'
```

Here is  what I have so far:

```
^([\x22\x27]?)[\w.&#]+\1$
```

`\x22` represents the " character, and `\x27` is the ' character.

This works in [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3i1bg), but not in Bash comparisons using the =~ operator. What am I overlooking?

**Update:** The problem was that my regex uses two features of [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) syntax that [Bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF) does not support: the `\w` atom, and backreferences. Thanks to [Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian) for reminding me of this. I decided to use `grep -oP` instead of Bash’s built-in `=~` operator, so that I can take advantage of PCRE niceties. See my comment below.

Comment: `\w` is a perl regex atom, `bash` uses POSIX extended regex instead

Comment: Looking at the various alternatives, I decided to go with something like this:
`if [[ $(echo "${string}" | grep -oP $regex >/dev/null; echo $?) -eq 0 ]]; then...`

This way I can use PCRE niceties like `\w` and backreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BASH regex doesn't support back-reference. In BASH you can do this.

```
arr=('"ABC&VAR#"' "'XYZ'" '"ABC.123"' "'XYZ&VAR#123'" "'foobar\"")

re="([\"']).*(['\"])"

for s in "${arr[@]}"; do
    [[ $s =~ $re && ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} = ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]] && echo "matched $s"
done
```

Additional check `${BASH_REMATCH[1]} = ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` is being done to make sure we have same opening and closing quote.

**Output:**

```
matched "ABC&VAR#"
matched 'XYZ'
matched "ABC.123"
matched 'XYZ&VAR#123'
```

Comment: Can we use just `[[ $line =~ \'[[:graph:]]+\' || $line =~ \"[[:graph:]]+\" ]]`? If so, can the way I used can be further simplified

Comment: Yes @Inian 2 different regex can also be used as you are suggesting. But using a single regex is usually more efficient. Use of `[[:graph:]]+` is a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp `(\"|\').*(\"|\')` for egrep.
Here is my example of how does it work:

```
a="\"ABC&VAR#\""
b="'XYZ'"
c="\"ABC.123\""
d="'XYZ&VAR#123'"
echo "Line correct: ${a} and ${b} and ${c} and ${d}"
if [ `echo "${a}" | egrep "(\"|\').*(\"|\')"` -o `echo "${b}" | egrep "(\"|\').*(\"|\')"` -o `echo "${c}" | egrep "(\"|\').*(\"|\')"` -o `echo "${d}" | egrep "(\"|\').*(\"|\')"` ]
then 
    echo "Found"
else 
    echo "Not Found"
fi
```

Output:

```
Line correct: "ABC&VAR#" and 'XYZ' and "ABC.123" and 'XYZ&VAR#123'
Found
```

To avoid so long if expression, use array for example for your variables.
In this case you will have something like that:

```
a="\"ABC&VAR#\""
b="'XYZ'"
c="\"ABC.123\""
d="'XYZ&VAR#123'"

arr=( "\"ABC&VAR#\"" "'XYZ'" "\"ABC.123\"" "'XYZ&VAR#123'" )

for line in "${arr[@]}"
do
    [ `echo "${line}" | egrep "(\"|\').*(\"|\')"` ] && echo "Found match" || echo "Matches not found"
done
```